# Automate logging into multiple macs at once

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, automation

I run a 4 display multiple monitor setup, where 3 monitors are the main mac, and the 4th is a secondary mac. I do this because the secondary mac is a separate machine and so I run things on there I don't want interfering with the main workflow. Things like OBS for webcam, side jobs like managing scanners/printers, multimedia (its crazy how so many music apps now are resource hogs), so on, so forth.

I want to keep these two machines behaving like one machine as seamlessly as possible. To this end I've got scripts that will ssh to the secondary mac and wake or sleep it when the main mac does so.

I want the secondary mac to login when I login to the main mac. I don't want to enable the autologin feature as I have a minimum security posture since I have clients and client data. Ideally I don't want to keep a password in plaintext anywhere.

Theres a lot of hits across the internet for [using an applescript](https://superuser.com/questions/39322/induce-mac-graphical-login-from-ssh) to automate login. Things like:

```
osascript -e "tell application "System Events" to keystroke "USERNAME""
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to delay 0.5';
osascript -e "tell application "System Events" to keystroke tab"
osascript -e "tell application "System Events" to keystroke "PASSWORD""
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to delay 0.5';
osascript -e "tell application "System Events" to keystroke return"
```

But I've not had any luck with that, I suspect perhaps I need to give some binary the right system access? Other things I've considered:

- It seems like it might have been possible with the old tools in MacOS Server but thats gone now.
- I've looked into possibly [automating it with ARD](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/remote-desktop/apd91b63ef0/mac) but I don't want to spend the money on that just for this.
- I'm unsure if you can script vnc type interactions.
- Using something like MicroMDM or similar MDM solution (free preferably)
- Some kind of third party macro running tool (hacky, unsure if it will fire pre login)
- The login sync feature of software like Sharemouse (just doesn't work for me for some reason, and the app is a black box, no way to debug) (also, being a black box, not the fuzziest feeling security posture wise)
- I did find [this script](https://github.com/brunerd/macAdminTools/blob/main/Scripts/setAutoLogin.sh) which toggles the autologin feature. its hacky but toggling this might work?

I'm wondering if theres some way to do this via either Universal Control or the Apple Watch auto login features.

This is surely a problem that people who run computer labs of macs run into so there must be some solution?

Comment: How about using a keyfob/smart card to login with a “tap”. What about Touch ID?  that may be worth exploring.  That said, you’re not going to find a software solution that synchronizes authentication - where signing into one machine signs you into another, that  would be a massive security hole